# Getting new computer case. How to remove COA label

Tags: computer-building, license, case

I am getting a new Case for my custom build but I already put the COA sticker on the side of my old case. Does anyone have any recommendations how to remove it without destroying it?

I thought about this possibility when I was putting the sticker on but decided that I would take the risk. Does anyone have any suggestions how they deal with this situation?

Comment: why not just write down the product key?

Comment: Because, if I'm not mistaken, the sticker itself is require for a valid license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a heat gun it will come right off.  (We use a very intense floodlamp placed right next to the case for this purpose, actually.)  It's a little safer than the razor blade method (at least, if you burn yourself it's probably just because you weren't being careful, whereas blades can slip).  It's a little more inconvenient simply because you're much more likely to have a razor blade around.

Comment: But I'd add that I don't know of any other good way to do this besides these two.

Comment: This is a windows 7 sticker. The XP stickers were sort of plasticy and your solution makes sense. The windows 7 stickers are more paper-like and appear to be almost designed to be difficult to remove. Does this work for Win 7 stickers as well?

Comment: I've only done a few Win 7 stickers but they worked fine.  You might need to get them pretty hot, though.  You're not loosening the sticker, you're loosening the adhesive.

Comment: Have you tried heating from the back? In other words, heating up the area of the case that the sticker is on? I don't know if it would work or not, just a thought.

Comment: Nope, never had a need to try it, works just fine from the front.  (If you're using adequate heat the case is gonna be really hot anyway.  We put ours on a side panel so this sort of thing is easier.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! A hair dryer worked for the COA label as well as my Core i7 inside sticker.

Comment: @lcode4food - Great. Wasn't sure a hair dryer would be hot enough or I'd have suggested it specifically. :)

Answer (score 2):

Carefully use a new sharp razor blade, using firm pressure and working at various angles until it is removed. Just did one last week. Be very careful and Don't cut yourself!

[image]

Comment: Where you able to re-apply it to the new case?

Comment: Yup, the sharp blade cut under the glue, just don't put your fingers on the glue side, you have to be careful because there are slits in the label to prevent you peeling it of in a normal manner, you have to work the blade slow and firmly from different angles, take your time it will come off intact.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cover the sticker with a piece of thick clear tape ( I use polytunnel repair tape).
2. Run the point of a craft knife around the edge of the sticker, and peel off the excess tape.
3. Ease up one short edge of the sticker/tape until you have a complete strip clear of the case.
4. Peel off the complete sticker from side to side, it should lift off the top printed layer in one go leaving most of the base layer behind
5. Apply a little white PVA glue to the back of the sticker and apply on to a piece of plain white paper. Rub between finger and thumb as it dries to flatten out.

If your sticker is already too far gone - I recommend downloading BERLAC ADVISOR. This is a great free program that will recover your installed COA and the Keys for most of the programs installed on your PC.